# Getting result using probability javaScript

Tags: javascript

Below is a code for a spin wheel I have made. What I want to happen is to get the outcome using probability. Let's say for no 1 I want it come at 20% chances, no 2 I want at 10% chances and so on. I am unable to apply this to the spin wheel using javascript. What are the ways in which I can do that?

```
(function() {
  const wheel = document.querySelector('.wheel');
  const startButton = document.querySelector('.button');
  const display = document.querySelector('.display');
  
  let deg = 0;
  let zoneSize = 45; // deg

  // Counter clockwise
  const symbolSegments = {
    1: "Frog",
    2: "Snail",
    3: "Dolphin",
    4: "Ladybug",
    5: "Koala",
    6: "Unicorn",
    7: "Dragon",
    8: "Snowman",
  }

  const handleWin = (actualDeg) => {
    const winningSymbolNr = Math.ceil(actualDeg / zoneSize);
    display.innerHTML = symbolSegments[winningSymbolNr];
  }

  startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    startButton.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    deg = Math.floor(5000 + Math.random() * 5000);
    wheel.style.transition = 'all 10s ease-out';
    wheel.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
    wheel.classList.add('blur');
  });

  wheel.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    wheel.classList.remove('blur');
    startButton.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    wheel.style.transition = 'none';
    const actualDeg = deg % 360;
    wheel.style.transform = `rotate(${actualDeg}deg)`;
    handleWin(actualDeg);
  });
})();
```

Comment: yes you can you need to sort to cheat a little put different weight to each object  like give 0-10 to 1 and 10-30 to 2 then when you have the winning answer get a random degree number in the range where the wheel is supposed to land

Comment: Can you please elaborate that

Comment: I mean I need to display the elements on the wheel as well. This this is the thing that is causing the main problem

Comment: random(range from 100) if 0-10 1 is the choice if 10-20 2 if 20-40 3 and so on. Then you have to figure out what degree range will make each option win. like a 10-20 degree turn is one 30-40 degree is 2. then pick a random degree within that range you can throw in a lot of 360s if you want they wont effect anything